# Swift - Array of AVplayers?

Tags: swift

I am putting together an app that plays drum beats based on hard-coded arrays as such:

```
var beatArray = [[String]]()

var beat01 = [["kick"], ["snare"], ["kick"], ["snare"]]
var beat02 = [["kick"], ["kick", "snare"], ["kick"], ["kick","snare"]]
```

Based on a set of parameters, beat01 or beat02 is chosen and when a button is pressed, an NSTimer is started with this following Selector:

```
    // THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS EVERY BEAT

func increaseCounter() {

    beatCounter++

if beatCounter >= beatArray.count {

    beatCounter = 0

}
    print(beatCounter)




    if beatArray[beatCounter].contains("kick") {

        kickPlayer.currentTime = 0
        kickPlayer.play()

    }

    if beatArray[beatCounter].contains("snare") {

            snarePlayer.currentTime = 0
            snarePlayer.play()


    }

}
```

kickPlayer and snarePlayer are AVAudioPlayers.
Since there are only two instruments, separately declaring each IF statement is fine, but as I add more and more instruments, this will soon be chaotic.

Is there a way to streamline this process? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
if beatArray[beatCounter].contains("INSTRUMENT") {

        INSTRUMENTPlayer.currentTime = 0
        INSTRUMENTPlayer.play()

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your players in a map

```
let players = ["kick": kickPlayer, "snare": snarePlayer, ...]
```

then

```
for beat in beatArray[beatCounter] {
  if let player = players[beat] {
    player.currentTime = 0
    player.play()
  }
}
```